# Regression for two continuous variables, with averages around each data point?

Tags: regression

I've been racking my brain over this one for awhile and it's time for me to give in and throw it to the forum to get your helpful opinions. I'm trying to perform analysis on a particularly bad little data set. I have two continuous variables - percent thaw of a site (independent variable) and tree growth (dependent variable). See figure below (you'll see why it's a pretty ugly dataset).

[image: Growth vs. Thaw graph]

The question that I'm looking at addressing with this data is "does the thaw rate of a site influence tree growth?". Each data point shows the mean amount of growth of all the trees at that particular site. If I treat these means as individual data points, does that mean that a simple linear regression is appropriate, or by using mean growth values of multiple trees at each site, are independence assumptions violated? I'm inclined to think that I can use the mean for each site and not have problems with independence (it would however be problematic had I used all individuals and not the means in the analysis).

Granted, there are still other assumptions that need dealt with in this dataset - but I can deal with those as long as I know that a linear regression is the right starting point.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to handle this is to use the averages at each site as data, but to use weighted regression with weights equal to the sample size at each site.

It doesn't look like you're going to find much of a trend, though.

Regarding your concerns about independence, it isn't an issue unless you think there is dependence between individual trees at different sites. Otherwise, the sites are independent of one another, and so are their averages.